# Multiply database schema in single Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to have multiply database schema in hibernate. I try with many Spring context on single Tomcat application (one context for each test scenario):

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.register(LocalBankConfig.class);
Map<String, Object> myProps = new HashMap<>();
myProps.put("simulationId", simulationId);
ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource("simulation.properties", myProps));
ctx.refresh();
```

and I use Spring annotation in business model:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
…
@Transactional
method
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work. Only EntityManager from the last created String context is injected.
Any ideas of how can i solve it out are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to have multiple persistence contextes. But you can easily manage multiple schemas through `@Table` annotation. From javadoc :

```
Example:

@Entity
@Table(name="CUST", schema="RECORDS")
public class Customer { ... }
```